# Does Slack provide API access to Slack's avatars?

Tags: slack-api

Where do the Slack default avatars come from? Is it their own service or a 3rd party one?

In either case, is there a possibility for others to use the avatar creation service / system e.g. via the slack API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [asked Slack directly](https://twitter.com/mikemaccana/status/650404978054561793), and they [don't currently offer this in their API](https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/650643817478160385):

> We don't have an API method or service for it, so there isn't a way to do this, sorry!

They've [heard the suggestion](https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/650648809186426880), though.